# In intelliJ Run/Debug Configuration, how to skip spring boot tests

Tags: spring-boot, intellij-idea, spring-boot-test

We have written tests using annotations like below,

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@Slf4j
@SpringBootTest
```

in IntelliJ 2017 we run spring boot program via Run/Debug Configuration, and it automatically execute these tests. But some tests really takes a lot of time, is there a way to disable or skip these tests? Thanks a lot.

Comment: you are using gradle or mvn?

Comment: I am using maven. But the program is not started via mvn but through right click the main class. I was thinking somewhere to put the -DskipTests parameter but don't know where to put it nor whether this actually will work.

Comment: try to add -Dmaven.test.skip=true in VM options?

Answer (score 0):

You can write a [junit category of runners](https://github.com/junit-team/junit4/wiki/Categories) or right click on package name or test-class and choose `Run "yourClassName"`, which will run only this class or all classes from selected package.

Comment: Sorry, I want to exclude these tests.